# Android - My application crashes if i pause, clear cache and resume

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, slidingmenu

#### In my project i'm using both actionbarsherlock and slidingmenu as libraries

I have the main activity extending this class:

public class SlidingSherlockFragmentActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity implements SlidingActivityBase which has his own implementation of findviewbyid

```
public View findViewById(int id) {
        View v = super.findViewById(id);
        if (v != null)
            return v;
        return mHelper.findViewById(id);
        }
```

the problem resides in the fact that when i resume my application after clearing cache, v and mHelper are NULL.
What can i do to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

This was a while ago, but did you use this?

```
View v = (View) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(your fragment ID here).getView();
```